# How to import Datetime function into python

Tags: python, mysql, datetime, google-bigquery, python-datetime

I am running a query that I plan on using multiple times. However when running this query the 'my-job1a' has to be different everytime so I was planning on making this go by the date time. Does anybody know how to implement the date time function for this?

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
client = bigquery.Client('dataworks-356fa')


query = query

dataset = client.dataset('FirebaseArchive')
table = dataset.table(name='test1')
tbl = dataset.table(name='test12')
job = client.run_async_query('my-job1a', query)
job.destination = tbl
job.write_disposition= 'WRITE_TRUNCATE'
job.begin()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe "my-job1a" is a constant string. and you want to change the string for new query.

```
import datetime
# "my-job1a" replace this with "my-job1a" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

job = client.run_async_query("my-job1a-" + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), query)
```

this will change for each second . if you want in millisecond then change the strftime function parameter. if you don't want such a big string , then change strftime parameter as per your choice.

Comment: When I write this I get this error 'TypeError: datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 16, 0, 28, 999204) is not JSON serializable'. This is the code i set it as a.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

Comment: please check your code !! this issue is might be related to some other problem. @W. Stephens